# Split fixed effect regression: ERROR in esttable() output "'nchar()' requires a character vector"

Tags: r, output, regression, fixest

I have been trying to run a fixed effect OLS regression using the package "fixest".
There are supposed to be multiple regressions generated (per year) using "split = "year"".
This seems to work without any errors but when I try to plot the regression reults using "esttable()" I receive an error:

--> Error in nchar(ROWNAMES) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

```
rm(list=ls())
options(digits = 7, scipen = 999)

library(fixest)
library(wooldridge) # for Dataset

data(crime4)
m1 <- feols(crmrte ~ polpc | year,  data = crime4, split = "year")
esttable(m1)
```

I tried to research the issue and follow the traceback, but don't understand the packages documentation on CRAN.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Dear MrFlick, you are right. I hope the issue is now reproducable for everyone, due to the public dataset. Thank you very much for the input.